# Best database architecture for friendships in a social networking application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, architecture

I'm working on a social networking website in Rails and currently I can think of a couple ways in which I can implement friendships (exactly like Facebook). But since a lot of the application's functionality is going to depend from this part of the application, I'm a bit apprehensive about committing to one, and then realizing that I could've done it better, and then doing migrations and changing the entire thing one by one.

If you guys could suggest which is the best way to go, it'll be great. Also, if none of my architectures are good enough, feel free to suggest a new one

**ARCHITECTURE 1**

A single table for friendships that has 3 columns -

- user_id (id of the user who sends the request)
- friend_id (id of the user who receives the request)
- pending (boolean to hold status. False if the request was accepted, true otherwise)

To get all friends of the user

```
  def friends
    user_ids = Friendship.where(
      '(user_id = :id OR friend_id = :id) AND pending = false',
       id: self.id
    ).pluck(:user_id, :friend_id)
     .flatten
     .uniq
     .reject { |id| id == self.id }

    users = User.where(id: user_ids)
  end
```

To get all friend request received by the user -

```
def friend_requests
  friend_ids = Friendship.where('friend_id = ? AND pending = true', self.id).all
  users = User.where(id: friend_ids)
end
```

*Advantages I can think of -*

- It requires the least number of tables and records in the database, as compared to other architectures. I'm not sure if this is actually an advantage or not as I've heard that the number of records in a table doesn't affect performance. So correct me if I'm wrong.
- Will require only a couple of validations. First that user_id be unique in the scope of friend_id. Second that user_id is not equal to friend_id.
- DRY code. Accepting a friend request requires just finding the record and updating just a single field (the boolean - pending). Un-friending requires just finding the record and deleting the it

*Disadvantages I can think of -*

- User.friends and User.friend_requests are not eager-loadable since they are not actually ActiveRecord associations. That can be a point of major slowdowns, in the long run, especially the search feature where I'll want to rank results by a number of mutual friends.

**ARCHITECTURE 2**

Two tables. One for friendships and one for friend requests - 
Friendships will be like -

- user_id (id of one of the users in the friendship)
- friend_id (id of the other user in the friendship)

Friend Requests table will be also like -

- user_id (id of one of the users in the friendship)
- friend_id (id of the other user in the friendship)

To get all friends of a user -

```
has_many :friendships,
  class_name: "Friendship",
  foreign_key: :user_id,
  primary_key: :id

has_many :friends,
  through: :friendships,
  source: :friend
```

To get all friend requests of the user -

```
has_many :friend_requests,
  class_name: "FriendRequest",
  foreign_key: :friend_id,
  primary_key: :id
```

Advantages that I can think of are -

- User.friends and User.friend_requests are eager-loadable. This can improve performances at a lot of places where I to eager-load the friends of a bunch of users in a single query, rather than hitting the database over and over and doing User.friends

Disadvantages that I can think of are -

- Duplicate entries for friendships. To make the User.friends association work, I'll have to create 2 entries for a single friendhsip.

---

```
| id  | user_id | friend_id |  
-----------------------------
|  1  |   15    |    30     |
-----------------------------
|  2  |   30    |    15     |
-----------------------------
```

- Which will require complicated validations such as: validate presence of row 2 (in above example) if row 1 is persent. And many others
- Creating a friendship will be complicated. It'll require

  - Deleting the entry from the friend requests table
  - Creating 2 rows in the friends table
  - I know it doesn't sound like a real disadvantage but to me it just seems like a lot could go wrong when creating/deleting 3 entries that depend on each other

I guess in the end the question boils down to -

Does having a lower number (half) of entries in the database (architecture 1) have significant advantages over more entries (architecture 2)?

and

How bad is it to have 2 entries for a single friendship? (architecture 2)

Comment: you might want to check out Hartl tutorial where he builds a basic social networking app for ideas

Comment: Have you considered swapping out database technology, graph databases like neo4j could be a better fit to the problem you are looking to solve

Comment: `+1` for graph databases, particular for Neo4J. It has amazing ability to utilize node attribute indexing, so typical graph operations with applied filters are blazing fast.

Comment: I think in the second example, you should still be able to get away with only one entry. You can use self-referential associations and define the relationship in the model. You might want to checkout Ryan Bates's railscast on self-referential associations  http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the second model, separate tables for `friend_request` and `friendship`.  While these tables may currently hold the exact same data, over time I would expect that they will diverge.

Here are some possible ways this might happen:-

- you want to allow them to send a message along with the friend request ("Hey, remember me from school")
- you decide you want to keep statistics about the friend request, such as when the request was made
- you decide you want to keep declined friend requests in the database (to disallow further requests once declined)

Because they are different things, you should create different tables rather than overloading a single table.  It's not so difficult to create a table.

Should you put two rows in the table, representing both directions of the relationship?  This is a question of *normalisation* vs *performance*.

The *normalised* answer is to only include a single row.  This model:

- is easier to get update/insert/delete as there is only one row to worry about
- more difficult and slower to query as you will need to query from both directions

The *de-normalised* answer (because duplicated data is stored) is to include both rows:  This model:

- is harder to update/insert/delete as there are two rows to keep synchronized
- faster to query as you can query from just one direction